# How to parse email address out of WHOIS results

Tags: .net, regex

Suppose I have a WHOIS lookup that returns results in the following format (simplified for this question:)

```
Domain name:           mydomain.ca
Administrative contact:
    Name:              John Smith
    ... other fields...
    Email:             johnsmith@gmail.com
Technical contact:
    Name:              Jane Doe
    Email:             janedoe@gmail.com
Name servers:
    ns1.mydomain.com
    ns2.mydomain.com
```

I want a regex that will give me the Administrative contact's email address (johnsmith@gmail.com), but NOT the Technical contact's email address. It's not important to verify the format of the email address itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex would be:

```
"Administrative contact:.*?Email: *([^ \n]*)"
```

You need to make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline.
Not sure how you do that in C#, but in python the matching (tested it and it works) is done like this:

```
match = re.search(r"Administrative contact:.*?Email: *([^ \n]*)", text, re.DOTALL)
```

You might also take into account that this is very inefficient for large files (having . match newlines is quite expensive), so you might take Jordan's solution into account too.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment about the '.' special character matching every character EXCEPT a newline reminded me of that fact, and put me on the right track. The workaround is to simply specify it with an 'or' to include the newline as well. I added a couple thinks like case insensitivity, and making the colon after the contact type optional. I also wanted to make sure the regex would not pick up the Technical contact email address if the Administrative contact didn't have one. Final pattern: (?i)Administrative contact:?(?:.|\n)*?Email:?\s*(.*)\s*\n(?:.|\n)*?Technical contact:?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to use a regex for this at all. Here's what I might do:

1. Split the response into lines
2. Scan for the line that reads "Administrative contact:"
3. Scan for the next line that has "Email:"
4. Extract the second word on that line

You may need to fine-tune this procedure as necessary.

Comment: I was afraid some one might try to spoil this with common sense :P. The reason I wanted to try regex's first is that I'm building a library to parse WHOIS results from several different thick domain registries, all of which have slightly different formats. My hope is to store a different pattern for each registry, but keep the rest of the parsing/lookup code the same.

Comment: @JordanRieger very nice idea! It is unfortunately quite true that different registrars have very different formats. Pity this is .Net, if it were Java I could have recommended parboiled... Does .Net have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just search for email strings in general, the regex for that is:

```
([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})
```

As mentioned before though, registrars can have very different formats on their pages, multiple email addresses, etc. which is going to make this a pain for you.

Comment: Yes, different *registrars* use different formats, however each *registry* (TLD) has its own root WHOIS server whose format does not change very often, if ever (see http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ for the list.) And since most TLD's use *thick* registries, the contact email addresses will indeed be available in the root WHOIS results. The biggest exception is Verisign's COM/NET registry, which is *thin* and therefore refers contact requests to the registrar WHOIS server for each domain. That is where my parser will have to be very flexible, as the WHOIS format might vary widely.